# capture the starting characters with many patterns

Tags: sql, oracle, regex-group, regexp-replace

I need to capture the starting characters from database objects with various pattern search.

I have tried using the REGEX expression ,below query i am trying and the expected data set to be.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
   owner AS schema_name, 
   object_name,        
   object_type,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME, '^([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_.*', '\1') as BEGINNING,
   count(*),
   round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 4) percentage 
FROM
   dba_objects 
GROUP BY
   owner,
   object_name,
   object_type,
   REGEXP_REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME, '^([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_.*', '\1') 
ORDER BY
   percentage desc;
```

***Expected Data Set***

```
OBJECT_NAME                     BEGINNING  COUNT(*) PERCENT
ABC_CUST_INFO_D                 ABC        20      .00010
BBC_CUST_ENTRY_F                BBC        100     .030
FHS_PRDCT_STST_T                A$f        194     .031
GHS_INVTR_CD_DRY                A1B        493     .051
#Tableau_6_sid:15251a_4i_2a     #Tableau   4000    1.5
/15722c29d_PhotoImageCameraPro  /15722c29d 5000    1.6
JAVA/15722c29d_PhotoImageqeeee  JAVA 5000  1.6
```

Unfortunately i was not able to separate the below

#Tableau_6_sid:15251a_4i_2a       -->   **#Tableau**

/15722c29d_PhotoImageCameraPro    -->   **/15722c29d**

JAVA/15722c29d_PhotoImageqeeee    -->   **JAVA**

how to resolve ?

so how to capture the last character after _ , below is an example

**Query 2 - capture the last characters**

```
 select 
   owner, 
   object_name, 
   object_type, 
   regexp_substr(object_name, '[^_]*$') ENDING, 
   count(*) COUNT, 
   round(100*ratio_to_report(count(*)) over (), 4) percentage  
from 
   dba_objects  
   where object_name like '%/%'
group by 
   owner, 
   object_name, 
   object_type, 
   regexp_substr(object_name, '[^_]*$') 
   ORDER BY 
   percentage desc
```

***Expected Data Set***

```
OBJECT_NAME                     BEGINNING       COUNT(*) PERCENT
ABC_CUST_INFO_D                 D               20      .00010
BBC_CUST_ENTRY_F                F               100     .030
FHS_PRDCT_STST_T                T               194     .031
GHS_INVTR_CD_DRY                DRY             493     .051
Teradata/jdbc/EXAcore/MPPReader MPPReader       5000    1.6
sqlj/modegen/engine/FuncInit    FuncInit        8000    6.0
moon/aio/af/ext/ISCII11$Decoder ISCII11$Decoder 8700    6.1
```

Unfortunately i was not able to separate the below

Teradata/jdbc/EXAcore/MPPReader  -->   **MPPReader**

sqlj/modegen/engine/FuncInit    -->   **FuncInit**

moon/aio/af/ext/ISCII11$Decoder -->  **ISCII11$Decoder**

Comment: Please, clarify, what do you mean by "starting characters"? You should describe the criteria in general words to formalize them to some regex not to [have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems). I mean, what shold be "starting" in this, for example: `qwe#_asd`, `_qwe/_asd`, `_qwe_asd`. Because I see you want to skip first backslash. Maybe it is better to use general substring? `substr(object_name, 1, regexp_instr(object_name, '[_/#]', 2) - 1)`, doesn't it do the work?

Comment: Also I cannot get the algorithm to calculate `A$F` and `A1B` from `FHS_PRDCT_STST_T` and `GHS_INVTR_CD_DRY` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the regex, you could add matching `/` and `#` in the character class followed by matching as least as possible chars until the next `/` or `_` using another character class.

If the pattern is not case insensitive, you could also add `a-z`

```
^([A-Za-z0-9$/#]+?)[/_].*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNwOJB/1)

If the `/` and `#` can only be at the start, you might also optionally match either one of them:

```
^([/#]?[A-Za-z0-9$]+)[/_].*
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3bSjtF/1)

Comment: Many Thanks , as of now looks fine , let me do testing and if any problem will get back

Comment: i have similar situation but in the 2ns case i am trying to capture the last characters can you please check ?

Comment: @rakesh That should be a different pattern? You could to that using for example `^[A-Za-z0-9$/#]+/([A-Za-z0-9$#]+)` if you allow the same characters https://regex101.com/r/e05m7D/1

Comment: @rakesh The is also an another way to use a single pattern with 2 capturing groups `^(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+/)+([A-Za-z0-9$]+)|^([/#]?[A-Za-z0-9$]+)[/_].*)$` See https://regex101.com/r/7VB3DG/1

Comment: I have tried  to test this logic - ^[A-Za-z0-9$/#]+/([A-Za-z0-9$#]+) in query 2 - regexp_substr(object_name, '^[A-Za-z0-9$/#]+/([A-Za-z0-9$#]+)')as ENDING, i am not getting the results as anticipated

Comment: @rakesh Are the strings the same as in the example? https://regex101.com/r/A933Vo/1 Did you replace with capture group 1?

Comment: can you please update this logic in the correct query (1 or2) in order to fetch the last characters of object_names

Comment: regexp_substr(object_name, '[^_/]*$') ENDING - it worked with this

Comment: @rakesh Ah, that would match any char except a `/` until the end of the string. But then you don't have to use a replacement, you can just get the match. If you don't want to match empty strings, I would use `[^_/]+$` to match at least a single character.